# Having trouble with Person class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I think I'm on the right track, but when I try to call for p.first_name. I get an error which can be seen in the screenshot, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[screenshot http://snag.gy/pj6ny.jpg](http://snag.gy/pj6ny.jpg)
Here is a link if you can't see it: http://snag.gy/pj6ny.jpg

Here is the code:

```
class Person 

    def initialize (first_name, last_name, age)  
        @first_name = first_name  
        @last_name = last_name
        @age = age  

    end  
end
```

Everything is fine when I enter

```
> p = Person.new("Earl", "Rubens-Watts", 2)
```

but it goes weird after that. Desired output is:

```
 > p = Person.new("Earl", "Rubens-Watts", 2)
  > p.first_name
  => "Earl"
  > p.last_name
  => "Rubens-Watts"
  > p.age
  => 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please use text, not images, to show textual information.

Comment: in ruby, instance variables are not directly accessed outside class.

and ruby's sweet syntacic sugar makes it look like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't defined a `first_name` method or declared any attributes. Try this:

```
class Person 
    attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age
    def initialize (first_name, last_name, age)  
        @first_name = first_name  
        @last_name = last_name
        @age = age
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the constructor with `new` the value are properly stored in the `p` object as instance variables. But they are not accessible from out the scope of the object if you don't write relative methods to read them, usual `getter` methods in OOP.

To do so:

```
class Person

    attr_reader: :first_name, :last_name, :age

    def initialize (first_name, last_name, age)
        @first_name = first_name
        @last_name = last_name
        @age = age
    end

end
```

If you need also to modify their value from outside, use `attr_accessor` instead, which provides automatically `getter` and `setter` methods.